# Angular ngForm breaks rendering

Tags: angular

I am having some issues with the forms in Angular. In particular, my page renders fine with this code:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div *ngFor="let f of fields" style="text-align:center;">
            <label [for]="f.id">{{f.label}}</label>
            <input class="form-control" autocomplete="off" required ngModel 
                [name]="f.name" 
                [type]="f.type" 
                [id]="f.name" 
                [placeholder]="f.placeholder"
            >
        </div>
    </div>

    <div *ngFor="let e of errors">
        <div class="error">
            {{e.desc}}
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

However if I add ngForm to the form tag, the view stops rendering without error

```
<form #testForm="ngForm">
```

I've imported the FormsModule from @angular/forms, so I can't think of why it isn't working?

EDIT: Chrome's console is spitting out this error:

> There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm"

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the error, did not have FormsModule in the imports array (I had the module.ts file open from a different project)